# Querying Mongodb for docs which have subobjects with a certain elem value within an associative array

Tags: mongodb

tricky mongodb querying problem: I have a collection 'Accounts' with a bunch of documents that (simplified and with actual data swapped for non-real-world values) look like this:

```
{"_id": "<Mongo Binary Data>",
 "Roles": {
     "D7753879C7020F8ECF947122FA211413": {
       "_id": "<Mongo Binary Data>",
       "OrgName": "ACME",
       "Rolename": "Coyote Liaison",
    },

     "CFA7722E6799170706E4C5FFF3F01E63": {
       "_id": "<Mongo Binary Data>",
       "OrgName": "ACME",      
       "Rolename": "MembershipAdmin",
    },

     "C7020F8ECF947122FAGIGHFVFF3F7753": {
       "_id": "<Mongo Binary Data>",
       "OrgName": "Initech",       
       "Rolename": "MembershipAdmin",
    }   
  } 
}
```

The keys in the Roles array are a combination of a role id and an org id which are then hashed, which makes it very quick to query (once an Account object has been loaded up from MongoDB and into C#) for if an Account has a given role for a given org, ie, is a user a MembershipAdmin for Initech.

Now I want to query for users who have a role for ANY org, which in pseudo-SQL could be expressed as 'SELECT all accounts which have at least one role object where Rolename = THISROLENAME'. Ie, get all users which are MembershipAdmins.

I have tried this:

```
{
  Roles.Rolename: "MembershipAdmin"
}
```

and this

```
{
  Roles: {"Rolename": "MembershipAdmin"}
}
```

and this

```
{
  Roles: {"$elemMatch": {"Rolename": "MembershipAdmin"}}
}
```

...to no avail and have seen several answers, etc, saying that the only way out of this is to push the associative array key down into the subobjects, which I don't want to do as it makes the primary function of this data structure (checking if an account has a given role for a given organisation) very quick indeed.  The use case I describe above doesn't have to be mega-fast as it is part of an admin user's responsibility so I'm happy to make them wait a few moments - so queries with excessive recursion, etc, are OK in this case.

Does anyone have any ideas how to make this work without refactoring the data structure? At my wit's end with this.

Many thanks,

G

**[EDIT: the structure above is not queryable, see the accepted answer for an erudite but quick explanation as to why not and what you should properly do to fix it. If you're OK with a hacky workaround, though, you can store a copy of the data in a BsonArray alongside it and query against that using $elemMatch]**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do with you want with that schema, nor is the schema very practical to begin with. You should change your schema to this :

```
{"_id": "<Mongo Binary Data>",
 "Roles": [
    {
       "hash": "D7753879C7020F8ECF947122FA211413",
       "_id": "<Mongo Binary Data>",
       "OrgName": "ACME",
       "Rolename": "Coyote Liaison",
    },

    {
       "hash": "CFA7722E6799170706E4C5FFF3F01E63",
       "_id": "<Mongo Binary Data>",
       "OrgName": "ACME",      
       "Rolename": "MembershipAdmin",
    },

    {
       "hash": "C7020F8ECF947122FAGIGHFVFF3F7753",
       "_id": "<Mongo Binary Data>",
       "OrgName": "Initech",       
       "Rolename": "MembershipAdmin",
    }   
  ] 
}
```

The reason why using nonstable values as document field names is so unpractical is exactly because it complicates most querying. The only upside is that some queries might be a little faster but given the fact that it also causes issues for indexing it's almost always a bad idea.

I would strongly suggest to change your schema to the above rather than look for solutions that allow your current schema.

EDIT: As mentioned in the discussion below it is technically possible to create the needed query using the $where operator. If you cannot do it any other way it means you have a schema smell and a potential scaling and performance bottleneck that will be diabolically hard to fix when your software goes live. Don't use $where. Ever.

Comment: I was afraid that this approach would be the only answer.  Thank you for the clarification and the reasoning behind it.

Comment: As an addendum, the structure in the question is what you end up with if you use a Dictionary<string, Object> in your underlying C# class to handle data such as this. It makes sense at the application level, even if it is not a practical structure when it becomes a mongo schema.

Comment: For the record, as an interim solution, have adapted the save method of my account class to copy the key data from the Roles Dictionary and store it in a BsonArray called MiniRoles. You can then query it with 
{
     MiniRoles: {$elemMatch: {"Rolename": "MembershipAdmin"}}
}
This is not an ideal solution, obviously, but will tide me over until I refactor my classes.

Comment: -1 because this is wrong. You can do it. I'm posting the answer below.

Comment: @CommaToast It certainly is not wrong. Your approach includes $where which runs on a single JavaScript context and does not scale or perform at all. It is not a safe or viable approach for all but a very limited amount of production level use cases. Frankly, hardly anyone uses $where and the JavaScript dependencies of $where and m/r are usually regarded as broken.

Comment: It is wrong, in fact, because you said "There is no way to do with you want with that schema", when in fact, there *is* a way to do it with the schema. It may have its drawbacks from a scalability standpoint, etc., but not everyone is working on large-scale enterprise applications here. If the feature is broken then take that up with MongoDB's creator, not me; all I did was actually provide a legitimate, working solution within the framework of what MongoDB offers.

Comment: As a side note, I'd really like to see them upgrade MongoDB to properly handle `{key:{document},key:{document}}` structures if that's possible. Once you've loaded an object from the DB it becomes so nice to deal with things in this fashion. I am not sure I understand why not possible to do.

Comment: @CommaToast Alright, "possible but never do it" it is. The reason your suggestion isn't possible is because it's not valid JSON but I agree that they should allow syntax similar to the AF, e.g. {oneField:"$anotherField"}. The primary argument against is probably that it will usually require MongoDB to load the entire document in memory prior to being able to perform the equality check or access two separate indexes.

Comment: I guess it's just limitations of JavaScript, since an ordered array with numerical keys is the accepted way for a set of objects to be stored. I still don't understand why the system cares if your array is ordered with integer keys in a sequence, as opposed to being stored in a non-ordered array using arbitrary-value keys; it treats the latter as an "object" and the former as an "array". Dictionaries are awfully useful when you know the key in advance.

Comment: No disagreement there but it could be argued that arrays shouldn't use dict to begin with. One of the many advantages of bounded arrays is that it gives guarantees about orders and successive indices which eliminates the requirement to store the keys completely. Why it is stored as a dict/map in BSON is a bit of a mystery to me as well. Apart from the additional disk space it takes (which may become relevant for larger arrays) the order guarantee is not necessarily present in the BSON data. Not sure if and how MongoDB resolves that if it reads such as a "broken" array from BSON

Answer (score -1):

**[EDIT]: This is wrong. Works if it were an array and not a hash structure. That, anyway was already tried in the question.**

`Roles.Rolename` can be used if there is an index on it.

```
db.collectionname.ensureIndex({"Roles.Rolename": 1 })
```

and then,

```
db.collectionname.find({"Role.Rolename": "MembershipAdmin"})
# returning only the organization field. Not tested though
db.collectionname.find({"Role.Rolename": "MembershipAdmin"},{"Role.Orgname": 1})
```

[Indexing Embedded fields](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-IndexingonEmbeddedFields%28%22DotNotation%22%29) from MongoDB docs has info on it.

Comment: Incorrect. His Roles structure is not an array due but an embedded document with hash values as entry keys.

Comment: My bad. Thanks for the correction. Had a similar problem myself the day before and missed out on the differences.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you do it:

```
db.Accounts.find({
    $where: function () {
        for (var index in this.Roles)
            if (this.Roles[index].Rolename == "THISROLENAME")
                return this;
    }
});
```

Note: I'm not sure why they designed regular MongoDB queries to not work if each of your embedded documents in the array has its own key, but hopefully in the future they'll fix that issue.

In the meantime this solution works great. I've tested it and it seems pretty fast.

Comment: Unless you have a very good and researched reason to do so you should always, without exception, choose schema refactoring over the use of $where so you can do native queries. $where should have been deprecated a long time ago.

Comment: I tested it and it works. I understand that MongoDB has the weakness of not being able to deal with an array of embedded documents in a structure like `[key:{document},key:{document}]` in the same way it deals with `[{document},{document}]`... but sometimes refactoring the data model is simply not an option. I am assuming someone is not here asking this question unless that was already ruled out as an option.

Comment: I meant `{key:{document},key:{document}}`, sorry.

Comment: It's not about it working or not. It's incredibly slow and cannot be executed in parallel for the entire process.